# Perform Permutations of a categorical variable in R

Tags: r

The dataset I have resembles something like this

```
dd = data.frame(X = factor(c("p","p","p","p","s","s","s"), 
                           levels = c("p","s")),
                Y = factor(c("ns","ns","ss","ss","ss","vs","vs"), 
                           levels = c("ns","ss","vs"))
                )
```

I need to fix Y and permute X.
Total permutations are 7C3 = 35.
I tried to use the function: **sample**, but the only way I can do it is run the sample for 10000 times and take unique vectors 
Is there a better way to do this? The above method will only work if there are small number of total permutations. 
Can anyone help me figure this out?

This is the code I used to create the 35 vectors

```
get_perm <- function(x){
  #This will work up to n = 6
  n = length(x)
  nperm = 10000
  all_samp = matrix(NA, nrow = nperm, ncol = n)
  for(i in 1:nperm){
    set.seed(i)
    all_samp[i,] = sample(x)
  }
  return(unique(all_samp))
}

X_perm = get_perm(dd$X)
```

Comment: Do you want `combn(dd$X, 3)` ?

Comment: Can you show an example of the results you are looking for?  Perhaps scale down to 5C2 and with 10 combinations you can show the exact result you want to generate, and we can help provide code that scales up to your actual data?

Comment: I added the code I used to create the vectors. Please run it on your system, I would like an output similar to that but using a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like below using `permutations` from package `gtools` + `unique`

```
library(gtools)
with(
  dd,
  unique(permutations(length(X), length(X), as.integer(X), set = FALSE))
)
```

which gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    2    2    2    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    1    2    1    1    1
 [3,]    2    2    1    1    2    1    1
 [4,]    2    2    1    1    1    2    1
 [5,]    2    2    1    1    1    1    2
 [6,]    2    1    2    2    1    1    1
 [7,]    2    1    2    1    2    1    1
 [8,]    2    1    2    1    1    2    1
 [9,]    2    1    2    1    1    1    2
[10,]    2    1    1    2    2    1    1
[11,]    2    1    1    2    1    2    1
[12,]    2    1    1    2    1    1    2
[13,]    2    1    1    1    2    2    1
[14,]    2    1    1    1    2    1    2
[15,]    2    1    1    1    1    2    2
[16,]    1    2    2    2    1    1    1
[17,]    1    2    2    1    2    1    1
[18,]    1    2    2    1    1    2    1
[19,]    1    2    2    1    1    1    2
[20,]    1    2    1    2    2    1    1
[21,]    1    2    1    2    1    2    1
[22,]    1    2    1    2    1    1    2
[23,]    1    2    1    1    2    2    1
[24,]    1    2    1    1    2    1    2
[25,]    1    2    1    1    1    2    2
[26,]    1    1    2    2    2    1    1
[27,]    1    1    2    2    1    2    1
[28,]    1    1    2    2    1    1    2
[29,]    1    1    2    1    2    2    1
[30,]    1    1    2    1    2    1    2
[31,]    1    1    2    1    1    2    2
[32,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    1
[33,]    1    1    1    2    2    1    2
[34,]    1    1    1    2    1    2    2
[35,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2
```

Comment: can you explain this

Comment: @animus You have three `2`s (corresponding to `s` as a factor in `dd$X`) that will be randomly located among 7 positions. That means you need to enumerate all combinations of those three `2`s out of 7 positions. `combn` generates the positions for `2`s, and you replace those indices in the initialized array of `1`s (via `rep(1, length(X))`) to get there.

Comment: Would this work if there were three levels or more?

Comment: @animus No, this is not applicable for more than two levels, but you can follow similar idea to modify the code

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. I tried "replace(replace(rep(1, length(dd$X)), v[1:2], 2),v[3],3)" but it still only generates 35 since I specified 3 in combn. if the vector is c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3) then we have 140 permutations.

Comment: I want to write a code where the number of unique elements is not a factor. From my point of view, the code I wrote is simpler but it's limited.

Comment: @animus Then you can try `permutations` from package `gtools` + `unique`, which can deal with factors with more than two levels. See my update.